# last Monday OF/IN May

Tags: prepositions

I've heard both "last Monday OF May" and "last Monday IN May", I guess the former is American and the latter British, or not?

Comment: I've heard both in America. I'm pretty sure they're interchangeable.

Comment: They're both good, as far as I'm aware neither is particularly American or British

Comment: No, they have different meanings. On the last Monday of May [year] versus last Monday in May, with or without year.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Monday%20of%20May%2CMonday%20in%20May&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMonday%20of%20May%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMonday%20in%20May%3B%2Cc0), both forms are used, but *Monday in May* is significantly more common than *Monday of May*. Changing the searches to American English or British English shows that the British have a much stronger preference to *in* over *of* than Americans do.

Examining some of the example uses doesn't show a particular distinction in the meanings. In the comments, Lambie suggests that *of* is used when referring to a specific year. But the corpus shows many uses in statutes declaring the days when particular courts are in session, and these refer to generic months.

The specific phrase *last Monday in May* has a huge burst in use starting in the late 1960's. This seems to coincide with when Memorial Day in America was changed to this date.